# ESP32 is stopping working

Tags: relay, solenoid, esp32

I am currently doing a project on automatic water level control. I have a solenoid valve and ultrasonic sensor. The solenoid valve needs 12 Volt to operate. So I have used a relay to connect it and used as ESP32 to program it. The problem is, when I am testing the code without connecting the solenoid valve with relay it works perfectly. But when I connect the Solenoid with relay it works when the water level is low. When the water level is full and the relay turns off, my ESP32 get stuck. It doesn't restart and it doesn't go any further and just sit idle! What's wrong here?

Comment: Do you have a free wheeling diode put across the load?

Answer (score 1):

If I were you I would check those things below:

1) I would provide +3.3V 0.8A power supply for the ESP's Vcc
2) I would add 10uF in parallel with 100nF capacitors near Vcc pins of ESP
3) I would put a flyback diode like in the schematic below in order to protect the transistor from reverse current due to coil inductance.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fOjrp8.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

4) I would also put a pull-up resistor at enable signal of ESP32 in order to prevent restarts that are caused from noise. 
5) And finally I would check what current my power supply can provide and how much current my whole system needs in order to operate. (Solenoid valves draw very much current at the beggining (5-7 times bigger than their nominal current) and they cause big voltage drops)